# Does an enemy unit that is being damaged move at slower speed?

Tags: command-and-conquer-red-alert-2, command-and-conquer-yuris-revenge

I have noticed that :

- An engineer move slower while being shot by cheap infantry.
- A standard tank (starting unit) moves slower while being shot by pillbox.

Is it just my imagination?
Is the assumption true for all cases (tank vs radiation, apocalypse tank vs pillbox)?

Please provide some reference.

Answer (score 1):

I played this game a lot and vehicles never slow down when they get attacked the reason you see them slowing down is for example when a unit is moving and something attacks it then it slows down because it changes its destination and target on the attacking unit or structure.

For infantry they animation changes from walking to crawling when attacked and that's why they slower

EDIT: A damaged unit moves slower even if its not attacked just damaged

Comment: Your deep analysis is useful, thank.  I probably should test and see it myself before asking for more reference/evidence.